# How do I hide previous <select> option based on the data attribute of another option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

**How do I hide previous `option` based on the `data` attribute of another `option`?**

I'm generating timeslots with PHP and checking against my DB if a specific timeslot is already booked. If a timeslot is booked I add a `data` attribute to the specific `option` with a value indicating how many timeslots before this time slot that needs to be hidden.

***The current output achieved:***

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectTimeslot">
   <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
   <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
   <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
   <option disabled value="19:30" data-time="2">19:30</option>
   <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

As you've noticed some `option`'s have a `data-time` attribute. The `data-time` value indicates how many timeslots need to be removed before this `option` to allow prep time for the kitchen on the booked order.

I would like to remove the total amount of `option`'s before the `data-time` based on the `data-time` value.

For example if `data-time = "2"` I need to remove the 2 options before the `option` with the `data-time` attribute. If `data-time = "3"` remove three (3) options, etc.

*Expected output:*

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectTimeslot">
   <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
   <option value="19:30" data-time="2">19:30</option>
   <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

I know how to remove a specific `option` based on a specific `value` however I don't know how to remove specific options based on a `data` attribute as there can be multiple `option` with different `data` attribute values.

I tried doing this with the `nth-child()` approach but struggling immensely.

Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I managed to get the following working to select the data attribute:

`document.querySelectorAll('option[data-time]').forEach((item) => {
  //Do something here to remove relevant options
 });`

Answer (score 0):

It would be *much* easier if your data could just output an array of times that should be removed.  Right now to find the piece of data that has data about other data that needs to be removed is really overly-complex.

If you could just have it output something like:

```js
var DISALLOWED_TIMES = ['18:30', '19:00'];
```

If you did this, the code would work like this:

```js
//From Server
var DISALLOWED_TIMES = ['18:30', '19:00'];

//Code on page
DISALLOWED_TIMES.forEach(v => {
   document.querySelector('#selectTimeslot option[value="' + v + '"]').remove()
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="selectTimeslot">
   <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
   <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
   <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
   <option disabled value="19:30">19:30</option>
   <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

However, that's just my suggestion and not related to what you actually asked.

---

Below is what I came up with to work how you have asked the question, but of course it is a bit more complicated.  Basically we have to reverse-loop through all options until we find one with the data attribute, save that as a number, and then for the next N iterations of that reversed loop we remove elements and update the remaining number of items to remove.  This is a lot more fragile than the above simpler code which is more explicit about exactly what needs to be removed.

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll('#selectTimeslot option');

var numLeftToRemove = 0;
for(var i = options.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
  var opt = options[i];
  
  if(opt.hasAttribute('data-time')){
    numLeftToRemove = +opt.getAttribute('data-time');
  }
  
  if(numLeftToRemove > 0){
    opt.remove();
    numLeftToRemove--;
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="selectTimeslot">
   <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
   <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
   <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
   <option disabled value="19:30" data-time="2">19:30</option>
   <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would do this serverside to 1) only provide valid available options to the client and 2) not require any processing by the client

Although since you tagged jQuery, this would be pretty simple with [prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) and [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```js
$('#selectTimeslot option[data-time]').each(function(index, option) {
  $(option).prevAll().slice(0, option.getAttribute('data-time')).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="selectTimeslot">
   <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
   <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
   <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
   <option disabled value="19:30" data-time="2">19:30</option>
   <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize `selectedIndex` with number of items needed to be hidden/disabled

```js
$("#selectTimeslot").on("change", function() {
  //Get the selected index
  var selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
  //Number of items to remove
  var itemsToRemove = $(this).find(":selected").data("time") ? $(this).find(":selected").data("time") : 0;
  //Reset the options
  var options = $(this).find("option");
  //options.prop("disabled", false);
  options.show();

  //Hide/Disavle the relative itmes
  if (itemsToRemove) {
    for (i = (selectedIndex - itemsToRemove); i < selectedIndex; i++) {
      //$(options[i]).prop("disabled", true);
      $(options[i]).hide();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="selectTimeslot">
  <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
  <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
  <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
  <option value="18:30">18:30</option>
  <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
  <option value="19:30" data-time="3">19:30</option>
  <option value="20:00">20:00</option>
</select>
```